# Python Keyerror 'sapi5', cant understand the error

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.8

One question of this type is previously asked but is not very helpful. I am using version Python3.8 in Windows 10 OS. I am getting an error, KeyError: 'sapi5'. dont know why this error is occurring. Please have a look at the below code given . My code is-

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)
```

The Error is quite big. can anyone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'ctypes.c_long'>, <class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.c_long'>, <class 'ctypes.c_long'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/saurav/Assistant/VA/MyAssistant.py", line 9, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 140, in <module>   
    ISpeechRecoGrammar._methods_ = [
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 125, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 2 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first uninstall pyttsx3 using following command

  pip uninstall pyttsx3
- Then install pyttsx3 version 2.6 using following command

  pip install pyttsx3==2.6